# 2 internet connections on a single PC

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, internet-connection, usb-modem

If I have a wireless and a usb internet connection on my Ubuntu 12.04 as in:

[image]

At the moment, Ubuntu seems to only make use of the Wired connection which is the usb connection.  Is it possible to get ubuntu to use the wireless connection without unplugging the wired connection?

So basically, as will, I would like to switch between the connections without unplugging any of them while leaving them both enabled.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You **can**, if is what you want, use 2 connections as one. E.g.:

```
Connection 1: 100Kb/s
Connection 2: 350Kb/s
Resulting connection: 450Kb/s
```

This is achieved using the technique *Bonding*.

How many bonding devices can I have? There is no limit.

It's a bit complicated to configure it properly, so I recommend you read [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) **completely**, and take away all doubts before starting.
And [in this page](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/bonding#Frequently_Asked_Questions) you will see FAQs, advanced options and all the information in one single page.

Answer (score 1):

you can use **ifup** and **ifdown** to enable and disable the connections without unplugging them . thats the easy way i know to switch between connections . open a terminal a type as

```
sudo ifdown eth0
```

to disable a connection with name eth0 and

```
sudo ifup eth0
```

to enable the connection & this way also applicable to wireless connections also . just replace the connection name with your wireless connection name .

you can list all your connections with `ifconfig -a`

hope that helps .

Answer (score 0):

What interface is used for outgoing connections is defined via the routing table. You can check which interface is used as the primary outgoing interface with `route | grep default` command and alter it with `route add default gw xx.xx.xx.xx`, where xx is the IP of the default gateway of the connection you want to use for outgoing traffic. You would need to delete the previous default gw before adding a new one.