# Using 2 internet connection in 2 program - ubuntu

Tags: networking, internet, chromium

I'm a newbie in this, I have an idea: I has 2 internet connection - ethernet and wifi. Now I want open 2 chromium window and choose internet connection for it. 1 window using ethernet and 1 window using wifi. Is it possible? Or I need using chromium and firefox?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's not how networking works. And as far as i know you can't tell firefox or chromium which interface to use.

Comment: However, what you can do is "_bond_" the two connections together so you get the combined bandwith of both of them: https://askubuntu.com/questions/158679/2-internet-connections-on-a-single-pc?noredirect=1. However, why do you want to do this ? Maybe there is another, better, way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I need that because in my office they manager all network in lan. So i want using my phone like hotspot and using it for private work. But i know a little about linux and i was think i can do it in linux. :D Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can design a device specific firewall with the `-i` option of the firewall `iptables` so that going to certain site would only use your wifi connection. A "DROP" policy can be set for ethernet with `iptables -i eth0 -P INPUT DROP; iptables -o eth0 -P OUTPUT DROP` and ip of sites be accepted as exception to the default drop rule with `iptables -A INPUT -s <IP> -j DROP;iptables -A OUTPUT -d <IP> -j DROP`